# PHP how to make a card thats between carousel buttons with bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-5

I'm trying to make a page where you can see the sold product so we can print a label and some different functions. This page can't be scrollable because it's gonna be on a touchscreen monitor. But I couldn't figure some things out:

- All images in our database are different size's, how can I make it that the image is large enough to still able to see the image, text and buttons at the bottom
- How to make the card be in between of the 2 button's from the carousel (so the previous and next button)

This is what I want it to look like

[image: This is what I want it to look like]

This is my code so far and this is also what I tried but couldn't figure it out, I haven't added the button's bellow yet because i first of all wanted to get the other problem's fixed

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


        </head>
<body>
    

    <div id="carouselExample" class="carousel slide">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <div class="card mb-3">
                    <img src="images/nmr1.png" class="card-img-top container-fluid" alt="..." >
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <div class="card mb-3">
                    <img src="images/nmr2.png" class="card-img-top container-fluid" alt="...">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExample" data-bs-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExample" data-bs-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</body>
```

```
body {
    background: #E0E0E0;
}

.details {
    border: 1.5px solid grey;
    color: #212121;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #212121;
}

.cart {
    background-color: #212121;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 900;
    width: 100%;
    height: 39px;
    padding-top: 9px;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 10px #212121;
}

.card {
    width: fit-content;
}

.card-body {
    width: fit-content;
}

.btn {
    border-radius: 0;
}

.img-thumbnail {
    border: none;
}

.card {
    box-shadow: 0 20px 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: You can use the `img-fluid` class. Eg:`<img class="img-fluid" src...>`. then come with button code question.